# select dataframe rows (datetimeindex) by a list of datetime.date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, datetimeindex

the df looks like this:

```
DateTime
2017-07-10 03:00:00    288.0
2017-07-10 04:00:00    306.0
2017-08-10 05:00:00    393.0
2017-08-10 06:00:00    522.0
2017-09-10 07:00:00    487.0
2017-09-10 08:00:00    523.0
2017-10-10 09:00:00    585.0
```

Question how to select row that in a list of dates:

```
['2017-07-10', '2017-09-10']
```

to have:

```
DateTime
2017-07-10 03:00:00    288.0
2017-07-10 04:00:00    306.0
2017-09-10 07:00:00    487.0
2017-09-10 08:00:00    523.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Datetime is index, try with the below:

```
to_search=['2017-07-10', '2017-09-10']
df[df.index.to_series().dt.date.astype(str).isin(to_search)]
```

---

```
                        1
DateTime                  
2017-07-10 03:00:00  288.0
2017-07-10 04:00:00  306.0
2017-09-10 07:00:00  487.0
2017-09-10 08:00:00  523.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Given that the dates in your list contain up to the daily information, you could start by flooring ([`Series.dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)) the `DatetimeIndex` up to the daily level and indexing with the list of datetime objects using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
t = [pd.to_datetime('2017-07-10'), pd.to_datetime('2017-09-10')]
df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df[df.index.floor('d').isin(t)]
```

**Output**

```
   DateTime
2017-07-10 03:00:00     288.0
2017-07-10 04:00:00     306.0
2017-09-10 07:00:00     487.0
2017-09-10 08:00:00     523.0
```

Comment: for example? we can still use the date accesor right?