# How to copy DateTime rows that matches Date values in List using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My `df` dataset look likes this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-04 08:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-05 09:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-02 07:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-03 08:00:00     5.2123
2017-01-04 09:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-01 07:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-02 08:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-03 09:00:00     5.4122
....
```

I have a list of `Date` like this:

```
# date_list could be of any size
date_list =['2017-01-05', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-12']
```

What I want to do is `copy` the next `2` `rows` of `values` starting from `'07:00:00'` `time` that matches the `date_list` including the `first` value to next `2` rows.

Basically, it has to copy from the `date_list` `date` and copy next `2` values with time starting from `'07:00:00'`

My new `df` will look like this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-05 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-06 08:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-04 08:00:00     5.2123
2017-01-12 07:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-13 08:00:00     5.2128
```

Here, we are ordering the new `df` per the `date_list` that is a `subset` of the original `df` with only `Date` values from the `date_list`

**What did I do?**

I used `df.index.isin(date_list)` to find the date, but my original `df` has `time` values. I also do not know how to get the next `2` values.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416474/3805553) with [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html), as long as your index is a DatetimeIndex.

```
import pandas as pd

# dummy data
date_range = pd.date_range('2017-01-03 07:00:00', '2019-01-31', freq='60T')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1, 20, (date_range.shape[0], 1)),
    index=date_range, columns=['Open'])

date_list =['2017-01-05', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-12']

df[df.index.to_series().dt.date.astype(str).isin(date_list)].between_time('07:00', '08:00')
```

Gives

```
                     Open
2017-01-03 07:00:00     2
2017-01-03 08:00:00    13
2017-01-05 07:00:00     6
2017-01-05 08:00:00     2
2017-01-12 07:00:00     8
2017-01-12 08:00:00    11
```